# Goldilocks size for matrix (between pmatrix and smallmatrix)

Tags: matrices

I would like to find a way (ideally a command like \begin{medmatrix}) to make a matrix halfway between the size of

```
\begin{smallmatrix}
a& b\\
c& d
\end{smallmatrix}
```

and

```
\begin{matrix}
a& b\\
c& d
\end{matrix}
```

Does such a command exist?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother, but there's `\medmath` from `nccmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
a& b\\
c& d
\end{smallmatrix}\right]
\\
\medmath{\begin{bmatrix}
a& b\\
c& d
\end{bmatrix}}
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
a& b\\
c& d
\end{bmatrix}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]